# Most effective way to redirect from mvc4 to another application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an mvc4 application that I am looking at hosting on azure websites. The only task is to take a code from a parameter and redirect to a page within our main application. We have a .co domain so we are issuing shortcodes like mydomain.co/abc I check the code in this example abc and redirect it to somewhere in our main application.

My question is do I just create a controller and do the redirect from the controller or can I do this before the controller? I want it to be as lightweight as possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A controller action taking the parameter, querying some data store by passing it this parameter in order to retrieve additional data and finally redirecting to the corresponding application seems fine. Another possibility is to write a custom route that will perform those tasks but IMHO having a controller action to do it seems easier.

Comment: Cool thats what I was thinking to. Thanks Darin

Comment: IMHO - Controller is the way to go !